# Is there a way to create multiple products with one Shopify API call?

Tags: api, shopify

The Shopify API allows clients to download lists (products, collections, etc) with 250 items at a time. Is there a way to also upload new lists with multiple items with one API call as well?  It looks like, from the documentation at api.shopify.com, that only one item can be created per call.  If true, would be both counterproductive and extremely inefficient for users trying to interface the storefront with an existing inventory management system, for example.

Let's say we have a store with 20,000 products and 200 custom collections where, for the sake of argument, a product belongs to only one collection.  Downloading information about the products would take 80 calls to products.xml, 1 call to custom_collections.xml, and 80 calls to collects.xml.  We would need only 161 calls to the API to perform the operation, and that number is well under the limit of 500 calls in 5 minutes imposed by Shopify.

However, to perform the opposite task (create or modify the same number of products, one at a time, according to the documentation) would require 20,000 API calls to products.xml, 200 calls to custom_collections.xml and 20,000 calls to collects.xml, which would take 7 hours to complete at 500 calls every 5 minutes.

Is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT** *I understand from the answers below that, indeed, the Shopify API does not allow creating/updating multiple products at a time.  This is, in my opinion, a significant shortcoming in an otherwise efficient product, so I leave here my request for the implemention of this feature.  For now I will have to create a service app that will be hitting the API non-stop, updating products as fast as possible.*

Answer (score 2):

**As of October 2019, the Shopify GraphQL API does have a bulk operations mutation, allowing for a large amount of work to get done. Probably not great for this use-case, but still, an improvement.**

You do indeed need to make 20,000 API calls to create 20,000 products using the API. API calls are rationed out, 500 per 300 seconds. You are correct on all points.

A simple script will ensure you respect the API limits, so just start it, and if it takes seven hours to complete, so what? You are not charged $ per API call. You could also avoid the API issue altogether and just upload all 20,000 products directly into the shop with Shopify using a CSV file. No API calls are burned there.

Comment: My comment for the "so what" part of your answer: 1) It's extremely inefficient to be hitting the API non-stop just to keep our inventory synchronized (read my comment in response to Edward);  and  2) It wouldn't be an issue if I had to do this once, or once in a while... but I need to keep the Shopify inventory system synchronized to our local inventory control software.

Comment: You are in a tough spot. The problem here is NOT the Shopify API, but instead is clearly your inventory system itself that is not amenable to online e-commerce. That is a shame. Sounds like you need to simply roll your own cart off your inventory system and move on... no need for something like Shopify.

Comment: I see it differently: the inventory system is flexible enough to interface with any API out there, JSON- or XML-based.  The problem is how Shopify's API is structured to update only one product at a time, making the process needlessly slow.  I think the Shopify API is on the right track, it just needs a small optimization. :-)

Comment: Cool. The difference is subtle. An API call that builds many products just for the convenience of less API calls would be very complex. Forcing you to make N calls for N new products on a simple API is superior to allowing you to make 1 API call to build N products. What you consider a small optimization is no such thing, it is a major architectural change. One small example, say you were 3/4 through adding new products with your one API call and you messed up your data and broke the system. What is the result? A complete rollback? Letting you know where you messed up? Not simple.

Comment: I agree with you in concept that a simple design is often times desirable, but in practice such design makes for extremely inefficient data flows, therefore warranting a second look at optimizations that may or may not be complex. IMHO the expensive nature of a roundtrip API call for each product is a good reason to justify the change (or at least the addition of a new function for such cases where one-at-a-time is too problematic to use).

Comment: Regarding the complexity of the task, I admit it may not be trivial but it's not very complex: client posts an array of product nodes, server returns an array of processed product nodes in the same order. A product that is successfully added is returned exactly as it is now, with maybe an extra field for result-code (201, 402, etc). A call only fails if the XML or JSON is malformed and cannot be parsed. No rollbacks necessary, as the server is still processing one product at a time. The only practical change is how the product list arrived: 1 call for 250 products as opposed to 250 calls.

Answer (score 1):

No, there’s no way to batch-create products through the API.

When working with an inventory management system, I recommend:

1. Waiting through the initial 7 hour setup or asking the merchant to batch-create the first load [using a CSV upload](http://wiki.shopify.com/Help%3aProducts#Bulk_Importing_Products_.28CSV.29)
2. [Registering for webhooks](http://wiki.shopify.com/WebHook) that tell you about just the product inventories that have changed so that you only have to update those entries in your centralized inventory system
3. Using `since_id` per this [article that talks about syncing with stores](http://wiki.shopify.com/Syncing_with_a_Store)

If you still need more breathing room, contact apps@shopify.com for a higher API limit, stating why you need it and how many more calls you need.

Edward, Shopify Developer Advocate

Comment: The big issue is that we do not plan on using the Shopify inventory management module. Our local inventory system maintains vailability/quantities, and even if I upload the products as a CSV first, I still need to update inventory quantities frequently. The way I understand it, there's no way to update the inventory_quantity field for multiple products either, so I'm left with the only option of writing an app that hits the API 24/7 updating product quantities?  Even with that extreme solution, I couldn't update the inventory availability more than a couple of times a day for all products.

Comment: I don’t follow; you say at first that you’re not planning to use Shopify’s inventory system, but you want to set the inventory_quantity field?

Comment: I didn't know at the time if that field was required for product update/creation, and I wanted to keep that number correct so we could use it in our liquid template (to print messages such as "Less than 5 in stock" or "Back ordered").  But we dropped that idea in light of the restrictions, so updating that particular field frequently is no longer happening.

Comment: So, after the initial creation of 20K+ products, the daily updates will be limited to the products that changed.  Still might take a while, and definitely could be more efficient and less painful if the API call took a list of products instead of just one.